# GMM clustering algorithm with equal weight and shared diagonal covariance

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, mixture-model

I'm looking for a Gaussian mixture model clustering algorithm that would allow me to set equal component weights and shared diagonal covariances. I need to analyze a set of data and I don't  have the time to try to write the code myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you can use scikit's GMM. It's easy to do, see the doc:

http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html

Re your specific needs:

```
thegmm = GMM(cvtype='tied', params='mc')
thegmm.fit(mydata)
```

Meaning:

- shared diagonal covariances: use `covariance_type='tied'` in the constructor
- equal component weights: use `params='mc'` in the constructor (rather than the default `'wmc'` which lets weights update).

Actually, I'm not sure if 'tied' implies diagonal covariances. It looks like you can choose 'tied' or 'diagonal' but not both, according to the doc. Anyone confirm?

Comment: Can you kindly tell how to find maximum likelyhood for each iteration while applying GMM.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [standard Matlab GMM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html) tool will work, set the `'CovType'` option to diagonal and the `'SharedCov'` option to true

Comment: You're missing a `,true,` after the `'SharedCov'`, so it should be `,'SharedCov',true,`.